# Is an app with password protected PDF files considered to contain encryption?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

If I include a password protected PDF file in my app, and upload to iTunes, do I need to say it contains encryption?

The app opens and displays the contents of the PDF file automatically, so the user never has to enter the password.

EDIT:

According to this pdf from the U.S. Bureau of Industry & Security: http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption/flowchart1.pdf

And this related page:
http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption/question1.htm

The product does contain encryption but falls under the exception rule:

Is the encryption functionality limited to intellectual property or copyright protection functions? YES

I'm *guessing* the way to answer in iTunes is:

Is your product designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography? YES

Does your product qualify for any of the exemptions provided in Category 5 part 2? YES

Comment: Thanks for the down vote.  I wasn't sure if it only related to being able to encrypt files / communications in the app or if there were exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since password protected PDF files are encrypted and your including it in your app.

Comment: I believe this is correct, but the app may qualify for an exception.  See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

In some way... i thing... yes:P
but i don't know the politics of itunes etc...
i think that application resources can be encrypted, without warning the public becouse you sell the app not the resources by it self

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, it uses encryption and is considered an encryption application.

The slightly longer answer is that under Note 4 to 15 CFR part 774, Supplement 1, category 5, part 2, the use of encryption solely for copyright protection does not require classification or special licensing.

See http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption/question6sub_2.htm

However, a complete answer would also include how the source code and related encryption technology are handled.  Source code is often subject to more restrictive treatment than the compiled and/or mass marketed app.

You can also call the Bureau of Industry and Security help line at 202-482-0707.  There's also a web page with Q's & A's at www.bis.doc.gov/encryption